# Why `push %rbx` only decrease `rsp` by 0x2?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am currently studying about how stack changed when calling functions. When I was using `gdb` to study `main` function, I noticed when pushing `rbx` with value `0x0` into stack, `rsp` decreased only with `0x2`.

So it seems this `push rbx` is identical to `push bx`, why?

code:

```
0x800060a <main>                push   %rbp
0x800060b <main+1>              mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x800060e <main+4>              push   %rbx
0x800060f <main+5>              sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x8000613 <main+9>              mov    $0x5,%ebx
0x8000618 <main+14>             movl   $0x64,-0x10(%rbp)
0x800061f <main+21>             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%eax
0x8000622 <main+24>             add    %ebx,%eax
0x8000624 <main+26>             mov    %eax,%edi
0x8000626 <main+28>             callq  0x80005fa <foo>
0x800062b <main+33>             mov    %eax,-0xc(%rbp)
0x800062e <main+36>             mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax
0x8000631 <main+39>             add    $0x10,%rsp
0x8000635 <main+43>             pop    %rbx
0x8000636 <main+44>             pop    %rbp
0x8000637 <main+45>             retq
```

at the very beginning, stack is like:

```
0x8000640           |   stack frame ($rbp)
........            |
........            |   ........ (stack)
........            |
0x7ffffffee270      |   stack top ($rsp)
```

then after `push   %rbp` and `mov    %rsp,%rbp`, stack is like:

```
0x8000640           |   stack frame (start)
........            |
........            |   ........ (stack)
........            |
0x7ffffffee260      |   0x8000640  rbp rsp
```

which is quite reasonable, however, after `sub    $0x10,%rsp` and `push   %rbx`:

```
(gdb) p/x $rbx
$1 = 0x0
(gdb) p/x $rsp
$2 = 0x7ffffffee248
```

Why `rsp` is not `0x7ffffffee240`?

Comment: 0x60 - 0x10 = 0x50.  And then another 8 from `push %rbx` is `0x50 - 0x8 = 0x48`.  In hex, 10-8 = 8, not 2.

Comment: Because you are treating values as decimal when they are hex. The difference between 0x10 and 0x08 is 0x08, not 0x02.

Comment: @PeterCordesP I am so stupid

Comment: @JiangFeng Don't take it hard.  It takes time to not use the number system you are used to using since childhood.  Eventually you'll get better at doing hex math when it is needed and you'll still be able to do decimal math when it is needed too.

Comment: @BrettHale It's just soooooo kind of you to encourage me! Completely Deeply Totally touched!  >_<